# GridView Not showing list of all page number at bottom in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET `GridView` control with a massive amount amount of data, which creates page numbers like:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.....

Instead of periods, I need to show all the page numbers in the `GridView` at the bottom. Can anyone see what's wrong with my code?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvContact" 
              runat="server" 
              AllowPaging="True"
              PageSize="1000" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CellPadding="4"
              ForeColor="#333333"
              GridLines="None"
              OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1RowCancelingEdit"
              OnRowEditing="GridView1RowEditing"
              Width="960px" 
              OnRowUpdating="GridView1RowUpdating"
              OnPageIndexChanging="GrvDetailsPageIndexChanging" 
              OnRowDeleting="GridView1RowDeleting">
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, add a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gvContact" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="1000" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowEditing="GridView1RowEditing" Width="960px" OnRowUpdating="GridView1RowUpdating"
            OnPageIndexChanging="GrvDetailsPageIndexChanging" OnRowDeleting="GridView1RowDeleting">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [PageButtonCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagersettings.pagebuttoncount.aspx) together with the `Mode="NumericFirstLast"` in the settings of your GridView, for example add this line inside the GridView:

```
<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast"  PageButtonCount="1000"  />
```